# vue-router: How to add `/` to the end of each link

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I have been using `vue-router` and it works perfectly. However for my project it is required to keep all URL consistent and have `/` at the end of each route.

Is there a way to do it? I could not find any option in doc.

Answer (score 1):

Closing this question.
The solution was to use
`pathToRegexpOptions: { strict: true }` 
for my routers.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  It looks like this feature is still not in stable yet, only 2.6+ beta

Comment: OK sorry, I was using `pathToRegexOptions` instead of the correct `pathToRegexpOptions` Must have copied and pasted it from somewhere

Answer (score 0):

I dont really know vue, but the express router should be equivalent to your problem.

in Express, you would do it like this:

```
var router = express.Router();
var users = router.get('/', function(req, res) { res.send('users endpoint') });

app.use('/users', users);
```

this would create a route like `localhost:3000/users/`

the trick is to add the `/` route on each "main route" or what you should call it.

i think that you've got something like this right now:

```
app.use('/users', function(req, res) { res.send('users endpoint') })
```

which will not give you an ending slash to your route.

#### i know this was a vue question but the mindset would be all the same just another framework of doing it with.

### Working Vue example

https://jsfiddle.net/tudpwhLo/1/

Comment: Lucas, thank you for your answer
yeah so when path is defined explicitly e.g.
`<router-link to="/user/foo/">`
it will have a slash at the end of URL.
However in the project i am using the name of route e.g.:
`<router-link :to="{name: 'about-us'}" exact>`
and in this case it does not have desired slash...

Comment: can you use something like a middleware or similar that intercepts that `<router-link>` that append the slash for you?

Comment: yeah, so i have added rule to nginx, but i think it will be much better to have an option to append slash when needed and render proper addresses directly at HTML.